# Capture all but last block in regex

Tags: regex-group, prometheus

I am trying to extract a value from a variable in a Prometheus relabeling configuration (regex-based). All values match the pattern:

```
[a-zA-Z]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)*
```

I want to fetch that value and strip the `-admin` part when it exists.

Examples:

```
foo-bar-baz     ->  foo-bar-baz
foo             ->  foo
qux-quuz-admin  ->  qux-quuz
```

If all values had `-admin`, I would have written:

```
- source_labels: ['__meta_consul_service']
  regex: '(.*)-admin'
  target_label: 'job'
  replacement: '$1'
```

but that is not necessarily the case.

I could probably have done that with a negative look-ahead (`?!...`) but it seems that Go does not support that.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: Not at all. I'm not sure why you would get that impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` is a greedy operator: it matches as much as it can. There is a non-greedy operator: `*?`.

It adds a "the shortest as possible" to the `*` operator.

The configuration changes from:

```
- source_labels: ['__meta_consul_service']
  regex: '(.*)-admin'
  target_label: 'job'
  replacement: '$1'
```

to:

```
- source_labels: ['__meta_consul_service']
  regex: '(.*?)(-admin)?'
  target_label: 'job'
  replacement: '$1'
```